# Efficient Mathematica Code for List Problem

Tags: list-manipulation, mathematical-optimization

Say we are given $f(m,n)=m \pm 2n + (-1)^n$ where $m>0, n>0$, $m$ as well as $n$ are integers. The problem is to generate a list of all the integers that will not be found in the list of values of the function $f$ for a particular $m$ and $n$.

I came up with the code for the 'plus' sign as

```
a = Complement[Table[i,{i,1,20}], Flatten[Table[m+2n + (-1)^n, {n, 4}, {m, 2}], 1]]
```

and the 'minus'sign as

```
b = Complement[Table[i,{i,1,20}], Flatten[Table[m-2n + (-1)^n, {n, 4}, {m, 2}], 1]]
```

After which I now executed

```
Intersection[a, b]
```

This gave me the result i wanted though it is highly inefficient because as $m$, $n$ increases, the codes take much time. I need $m$, $n$ up to about $10^9$.

I want an efficient code that will be executed once.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: To be honest, I don't quite understand your explanation of what you want to do. You want the complement of the range of $f$ for a given maximum $m$ and $n$? Could you add some more detail. As it stands, I don't see how your code is supposed to solve your problem.

Comment: Do you want to make a function that does this for some predetermined range? Give it assumptions of the use of integers—then to answer your question, find the trend and—or what you could do is just make the list of f(m,n) up to the value, then `DeleteCases` with the range you used to generate f(m, n) and you should be good from there!

Comment: you can use `Complement` only once: `Complement[Range[20], Flatten[Table[m+2n + (-1)^n, {n, 4}, {m, 2}], 1], Flatten[Table[m - 2n + (-1)^n, {n, 4}, {m, 2}], 1]]`

Comment: @kglr my guess, though, is there is some easy analytical-type solution to this thing once we know what the intended operation of the function should be...

Comment: @kglr Thanks a lot.That was simple and fantastic but do you think it could be efficient for m,n as big as my target?

Comment: @b3m2a1 So sorry I couldn't pose a clearer question. All the same your guess is good. Thanks.

Comment: All the elements contributed by the $n$ term are $1+4 n$, and $m$ spans all the naturals. You should be able to distribute the intersection and complement expression. Is the $20$ in `Table[i,{i,1,20}]` a fixed number?

Comment: BTW, Hi and welcome to Mma.SE. Start by **taking the [tour] now** and learning about [asking](https://wolfr.am/wb2ijD7O) and what's [on-topic](https://wolfr.am/wb2ijD7O). Always [edit] if improvable, show due diligence. Thanks for your minimal working example of code in properly [formatted form](https://goo.gl/ELLhTX). By doing all this you help us to help you and likely you will inspire great answers. The site depends on participation, as you receive **give back:** vote and answer questions, keep the site useful, be kind, correct mistakes and share what you have learned.

Comment: @rhermans The 20 is not fixed, it can be increased if need be.

Comment: It seems to me that as soon as the `m` iterator is as big as `{m, 4}`, you get a run of consecutive integers.  If `{m, 3}`, the complement consists of all the integers (in the range of the table) that are congruent to 1 mod 4.  And so on.

Comment: Are you using $n$ for different things (20 and 1--4 as well as running indices)? Is this intended?